# Concrete garage floor

Tags: concrete, paint, polyurethane, finish

A 24'x 30' concrete garage floor. How many gallons of polyurethane floor paint do I need to buy to cover with a good coat?

Comment: How many square feet per gallon does the can say it covers?

Comment: Have you read the instructions on any can of paint at the store? They _all_ give an estimated coverage.

Answer (score 1):

720/[stated coverage per gallon] per coat.

Probably will need at least 2 coats.